# Arithmetic Boolean Algebra with Multiple Inputs

Tags: math, boolean, boolean-logic, algebra

I've been working with a half-byte register with four nibbles W, X, Y and Z; for a seven-segment LED display I'm trying to replicate in CSS... All of the nibbles naturally would receive a 0 or 1 pulse; and then I process each of the pulses with the Boolean equations I have, which would then result in each segment being turned on (1) or off (0) based on the result derived from each of the seven equations...

I've found that I can make this task easier for myself by converting each Boolean equation to a mathematical equation using the following equivalents (referencing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations)

```
A AND B = A * B
A OR B = A + B - (A * B)
NOT A = 1 - A
```

where `A` and `B` can only equal 0 or 1... This process is simple enough when dealing with two inputs... but what does one do with four inputs like W, X, Y and Z?

For example, my Boolean equation for Segment A (top of the LED display) is:

`(W AND NOT(X) AND NOT(Y)) OR (W AND NOT(Z)) OR (NOT(W) AND X AND Z) OR (NOT(W) AND Y) OR (X AND Y) OR (NOT(X) AND NOT(Z))`

where `W` is the most significant bit, and `Z` is the least significant bit... What are the rules for dealing with multiple inputs in this instance? Can someone give me a nudge as to how to proceed?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Take a look at [BCD to 7 seg decoder](https://www.electronicshub.org/bcd-7-segment-led-display-decoder-circuit/). If you don't want to use OR operation you can convert the functions to NANDs only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I kinda racked my brains trying to work out a means to do this... The AND representations within the Boolean equations were easy enough, as were the NOT representations, but the OR processes were killing me...

What I hadn't realized at first is that these Boolean equations can be solved to eliminate the OR references to a format that was easier to translate arithmetically...

**The Process**

1. We take our Boolean equation: `(w AND NOT(x) AND NOT(y)) OR (w AND NOT(z)) OR (NOT(w) AND x AND z) OR (NOT(w) AND y) OR (x AND y) OR (NOT(x) AND NOT(z))`
2. Next, we pop it into WolframAlpha.com's engine... I didn't realize until I tested it out that WolframAlpha is capable of re-writing logic equations... And it was also capable of re-writing them with respect to AND gates and NOT gates only... As a result, my equation was re-written as `¬(w ∧ x ∧ ¬y ∧ z) ∧ ¬(w ∧ ¬x ∧ y ∧ z) ∧ ¬(¬w ∧ x ∧ ¬y ∧ ¬z) ∧ ¬(¬w ∧ ¬x ∧ ¬y ∧ z)`
3. Now that I had my Boolean equation re-written with respect to AND and NOT gates, I converted the symbols back to the English equivalents so that I didn't get a migraine reading it: `NOT(w AND x AND NOT(y) AND z) AND NOT(w AND NOT(x) AND y AND z) AND NOT(NOT(w) AND x AND NOT(y) AND NOT(z)) AND NOT(NOT(w) AND NOT(x) AND NOT(y) AND z)`
4. Now, using the arithmetic rules I mentioned in my initial post, wrote the arithmetic equivalent out:

`(1-(w*x*(1-y)*z))*(1-(w*(1-x)*y*z))*(1-((1-w)*x*(1-y)*(1-z)))*(1-((1-w)*(1-x)*(1-y)*z))`
 5. Next, I stuck this back into WolframAlpha, and waited...

What came out was a little... unexpected:

[image]

I knew this would take some time to simplify...

Luckily, WolframAlpha has an option to export certain answers into plain text... I took advantage of this and copied and pasted it into a text editor...

```
x^4y^4z^4w^4-2x^3y^4z^4w^4+x^2y^4z^4w^4-3x^4y^3z^4w^4+6x^3y^3z^4w^4
-3x^2y^3z^4w^4+3x^4y^2z^4w^4-6x^3y^2z^4w^4+3x^2y^2z^4w^4-x^4yz^4w^4
+2x^3yz^4w^4-x^2yz^4w^4-x^4y^4z^3w^4+2x^3y^4z^3w^4-x^2y^4z^3w^4
+3x^4y^3z^3w^4-6x^3y^3z^3w^4+3x^2y^3z^3w^4-3x^4y^2z^3w^4+6x^3y^2z^3w^4
-3x^2y^2z^3w^4+x^4yz^3w^4-2x^3yz^3w^4+x^2yz^3w^4-2x^4y^4z^4w^3+4x^3y^4z^4w^3
-2x^2y^4z^4w^3+6x^4y^3z^4w^3-12x^3y^3z^4w^3+6x^2y^3z^4w^3-6x^4y^2z^4w^3
+12x^3y^2z^4w^3-6x^2y^2z^4w^3+2x^4yz^4w^3-4x^3yz^4w^3+2x^2yz^4w^3+2x^4y^4z^3w^3
-4x^3y^4z^3w^3+2x^2y^4z^3w^3-x^3z^3w^3-6x^4y^3z^3w^3+16x^3y^3z^3w^3
-12x^2y^3z^3w^3+2xy^3z^3w^3+x^2z^3w^3+6x^4y^2z^3w^3-21x^3y^2z^3w^3
+19x^2y^2z^3w^3-4xy^2z^3w^3-2x^4yz^3w^3+10x^3yz^3w^3-10x^2yz^3w^3+2xyz^3w^3
+x^3z^2w^3-3x^3y^3z^2w^3+4x^2y^3z^2w^3-xy^3z^2w^3-x^2z^2w^3+7x^3y^2z^2w^3
-9x^2y^2z^2w^3+2xy^2z^2w^3-5x^3yz^2w^3+6x^2yz^2w^3-xyz^2w^3+x^4y^4z^4w^2
-2x^3y^4z^4w^2+x^2y^4z^4w^2-3x^4y^3z^4w^2+6x^3y^3z^4w^2-3x^2y^3z^4w^2
+3x^4y^2z^4w^2-6x^3y^2z^4w^2+3x^2y^2z^4w^2-x^4yz^4w^2+2x^3yz^4w^2-x^2yz^4w^2
-x^4y^4z^3w^2+2x^3y^4z^3w^2-x^2y^4z^3w^2+2x^3z^3w^2+3x^4y^3z^3w^2
-12x^3y^3z^3w^2+12x^2y^3z^3w^2-3xy^3z^3w^2-2x^2z^3w^2-3x^4y^2z^3w^2
+20x^3y^2z^3w^2-23x^2y^2z^3w^2+6xy^2z^3w^2+x^4yz^3w^2-12x^3yz^3w^2
+14x^2yz^3w^2-3xyz^3w^2-2x^3z^2w^2+5x^3y^3z^2w^2-7x^2y^3z^2w^2+2xy^3z^2w^2
+5x^2z^2w^2-12x^3y^2z^2w^2+22x^2y^2z^2w^2-10xy^2z^2w^2+y^2z^2w^2-2xz^2w^2
+9x^3yz^2w^2-20x^2yz^2w^2+10xyz^2w^2-yz^2w^2-2x^2zw^2-3x^2y^2zw^2+2xy^2zw^2
+xzw^2+5x^2yzw^2-3xyzw^2-x^3z^3w+2x^3y^3z^3w-3x^2y^3z^3w+xy^3z^3w+x^2z^3w
-5x^3y^2z^3w+7x^2y^2z^3w-2xy^2z^3w+4x^3yz^3w-5x^2yz^3w+xyz^3w+x^3z^2w
-2x^3y^3z^2w+3x^2y^3z^2w-xy^3z^2w-5x^2z^2w+5x^3y^2z^2w-13x^2y^2z^2w
+8xy^2z^2w-y^2z^2w+3xz^2w-4x^3yz^2w+15x^2yz^2w-10xyz^2w+yz^2w+xw-xyw
+3x^2zw+4x^2y^2zw-3xy^2zw-5xzw-7x^2yzw+9xyzw-2yzw+zw+x^2z^2+x^2y^2z^2
-xy^2z^2-xz^2-2x^2yz^2+2xyz^2-x+xy-x^2z-x^2y^2z+xy^2z+3xz+2x^2yz-4xyz+yz-z+1
```

Simplifying this on the fly would be a pain... and it then occurred to me there was a way to reduce this considerably, especially considering I was currently dealing with a quartic polynomial.

5. Because `w`, `x`, `y` and `z` were essentially pulses, either with a value of `0` or `1`, `w^4` or `x^3` or `y^2` and so on were going to boil down to `w`, `x`, `y` or `z`; simply because `1^n = 1` and `0^n = 0` for `n>0`; so put simply...

[image]

A couple of global replaces later, this "reduced" my equation to the following:

```
xyzw-2xyzw+xyzw-3xyzw+6xyzw-3xyzw+3xyzw-6xyzw+3xyzw-xyzw+2xyzw-xyzw-xyzw+2xyzw
-xyzw+3xyzw-6xyzw+3xyzw-3xyzw+6xyzw-3xyzw+xyzw-2xyzw+xyzw-2xyzw+4xyzw-2xyzw
+6xyzw-12xyzw+6xyzw-6xyzw+12xyzw-6xyzw+2xyzw-4xyzw+2xyzw+2xyzw-4xyzw+2xyzw-xzw
-6xyzw+16xyzw-12xyzw+2xyzw+xzw+6xyzw-21xyzw+19xyzw-4xyzw-2xyzw+10xyzw-10xyzw
+2xyzw+xzw-3xyzw+4xyzw-xyzw-xzw+7xyzw-9xyzw+2xyzw-5xyzw+6xyzw-xyzw+xyzw-2xyzw
+xyzw-3xyzw+6xyzw-3xyzw+3xyzw-6xyzw+3xyzw-xyzw+2xyzw-xyzw-xyzw+2xyzw-xyzw+2xzw
+3xyzw-12xyzw+12xyzw-3xyzw-2xzw-3xyzw+20xyzw-23xyzw+6xyzw+xyzw-12xyzw+14xyzw
-3xyzw-2xzw+5xyzw-7xyzw+2xyzw+5xzw-12xyzw+22xyzw-10xyzw+yzw-2xzw+9xyzw-20xyzw
+10xyzw-yzw-2xzw-3xyzw+2xyzw+xzw+5xyzw-3xyzw-xzw+2xyzw-3xyzw+xyzw+xzw-5xyzw
+7xyzw-2xyzw+4xyzw-5xyzw+xyzw+xzw-2xyzw+3xyzw-xyzw-5xzw+5xyzw-13xyzw+8xyzw
-yzw+3xzw-4xyzw+15xyzw-10xyzw+yzw+xw-xyw+3xzw+4xyzw-3xyzw-5xzw-7xyzw+9xyzw
-2yzw+zw+xz+xyz-xyz-xz-2xyz+2xyz-x+xy-xz-xyz+xyz+3xz+2xyz-4xyz+yz-z+1
```

6. Lastly, after re-writing the terms back into alphabetic order, I sliced up the equation into smaller pieces that could be inputted into WolframAlpha to get simplified snippets that were basically re-glued back together... Eventually my arithmetic equivalent of `(w AND NOT(x) AND NOT(y)) OR (w AND NOT(z)) OR (NOT(w) AND x AND z) OR (NOT(w) AND y) OR (x AND y) OR (NOT(x) AND NOT(z))` resulted in `4wxyz-wxy-3wxz+wx-2wyz+wz-2xyz+xy+2xz-x+yz-z+1`; which, when I tested it against my original truth table for Segment A, plugging in values of 0 or 1 for the sixteen different possibilities from `0000` to `1111` yielded the exact results I had determined...

Now I just have to repeat this process with the other six segments... [Sigh]

I hope this helps anyone else considering reducing a Boolean equation mathematically...

Comment: And this is a simplification, is it?

Comment: Well, it's the algebraic equivalent to the logic needed to display segment A for a hexadecimal output when inputting the four bits. But it's what I needed... So yes, it is "simpler" ;)